# jQuery: select divs where all select inside does not have 0 value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="subform_uploading" id="subform1">
    <select class="form_file">
        <option value="0">Select file</option>
        <option value="file1">file1</option>
        ...
        <option value="file10">file10</option>
    <select>
    <select class="form_title">
        <option value="0">Select Title</option>
        <option value="title1">title1</option>
        ...
        <option value="title10">title10</option>
    <select>
</div>
...
<div class="subform_uploading" id="subform5">
    <select class="form_file">
        <option value="0">Select file</option>
        <option value="file1">file1</option>
        ...
        <option value="file10">file10</option>
    <select>
    <select class="form_title">
        <option value="0">Select Title</option>
        <option value="title1">title1</option>
        ...
        <option value="title10">title10</option>
    <select>
</div>
```

What I like to get with jQuery is number of div elements with "subform_uploading" class where both select values are not equal to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to compare the number of `<select>` elements within each `<div>` against the number of `<select>` elements in each `<div>` where the value is not `0`:

```
var numDivs = $('div.subform_uploading').filter(function() {

  var $this = $(this), 
      $select = $this.find('select');

  return $select.length == $select.filter(function() { return this.value != 0 }).length; 

}).length;
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/3C5BA/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try a filter like

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var $els = $('.subform_uploading').filter(function () {
        return $(this).find('select').filter(function () {
            return $(this).val() == 0
        }).length == 0;
    });
    console.log($els, $els.length)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/t6R8R/)

Comment: Thanks for response. But it outputs number of divs where both select elements have value 0, as I understand. I need number of divs, where both select is not equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = 0;
$('.subform_uploading').each(function(i) {
    select1 = $(this).find('select').eq(0).val();
    select2 = $(this).find('select').eq(1).val();
    if(select1 != '0' && select2 != '0') {
        count++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a way using a one liner jquery selector. 
THis function though will return what you wanted.

Demo : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7nja/)

```
function getDivs () {
    var outDivs = [];
    var divs = $('div.subform_uploading');
    divs.each (function ( ) {
       var sels =   $(this).find ('select option[value!="0"]:selected');
       if (sels.length == 2) {
            outDivs.push ( $(this) );
       }
   });
   return outDivs;
 }
```